# Hide DateField while clicking anywhere in page

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to hide extjs date-field on clicking anywhere on DOM except date-field. while clicking anywhere in dom bodyClick function get called.On basis of page co-ordinates element object get retrieved  and then this element object get compared with date-field object.This works fine but problem comes whenever i am clicking on date-picker again "date-field" get hide.

sample code -

```
  bodyClick: function(e){
       var me = this, elem, t;
      var flag =true;
        elem = me.getEl();
      for(t = Ext.dom.Element.fromPoint(e.getX(), e.getY()); t && t != null;){
        if (Ext.fly(elem ).contains(t)){
            flag =false;
        } 
       }

      if(flag ){
        me.hide();
      }
    }
```

[image]

Any Suggestions for hiding datefield while clicking anywhere in DOM (extJs).

Answer (score 4):

You can try this in afterRender of the panel or container in which your component is in.

```
   this.mon(Ext.getBody().getEl(), 'click', this.yourFunction, this);

    yourFunction:function(e){
          var comp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('datepicker')[0];//Get your datepicker component
          if (Ext.fly(e.getTarget()) != comp) {  //get the target using Ext.fly
                  comp.hide();              //Hide the component if the target is not the datepicker
              }

    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey sreek thanks man.. I have tried this but some how target not matched with datepicker object.Target gives current object, Anyhow if we get target's top parent object then we can compare it with datepicker object.